# Learning GAP software

Tags: reference-request, gap

I wants to use the application GAP. Please help me, how should I start and from where? I need this to compute some specific structures. Thanks for help!

Comment: not PARI GP ? or Mathematica ?

Comment: From the tag you included: Please note that GAP Forum or GAP Support may be more suitable places for questions about GAP: see http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html

Comment: I suggest you look at the web pages at http://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Learning/learning.html

Comment: Also see [Which resources are available to self-study GAP?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104195/which-resources-are-available-to-self-study-gap/369307#369307) and [Royal way to learn algorithmic / computational / computer algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353307/royal-way-to-learn-algorithmic-computational-computer-algebra/2362055#2362055)

Comment: [Gallian's manual](https://college.cengage.com/mathematics/gallian/abstract_algebra/5e/shared/gap/gap_manual.pdf) can be of interest.