# Learn Algebra with computational applications [Book Recommendation]

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation, computational-algebra

I am studying Linear and abstract algebra and find it a bit too, again "abstract", could someone recommend me a good book so I can learn it through computational applications? I think it will make the learning process easier for me.

Kind regards.

Comment: Computational applications are a different area, e.g., solving systems of polynomial equations with Gröbner bases. I suppose you just need many concrete examples for groups, rings, fields and such things.For recommendations see this site here, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54839/good-abstract-algebra-books-for-self-study).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Could you recommend me a computational application book anyhow? Thanks.

Comment: A famous book using computational methods in algebra and geometry is [this one](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783319167206) for example.

Comment: While it's not a textbook there are many resource for learning about the OpenGL transform in computer graphics which relies heavily on linear algebra to solve geometric problems. It's a common application with easy to visualize results that I found to be useful.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Coding-Python-application-ebook/dp/B08CT47RL3                        I am looking for something similar to this but more oriented to Abstract Algebra, symbolic computations, and so on..

Comment: For Linear Algebra, I'm a fan of Gilbert Strang's linear algebra books such as Linear Algebra and Its Applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed while reading Wikipedia a while back that one of our better contributors, Derek F. Holt, authored a book with Eick and O'Brien called *Handbook of Computational Group Theory*.

He appears,  based on his posts, to know a lot about the subject,  and group theory in general.

---

Also, while I haven't used it myself,  I have gathered that GAP is a very useful tool for the subject.   I suggest looking into it.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning GAP! I have a couple of posts related to using GAP to learn algebra [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947239/novel-approaches-to-elementary-number-theory-and-abstract-algebra/967298#967298) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353307/royal-way-to-learn-algorithmic-computational-computer-algebra/2362055#2362055) with some references.